# Multiple ForeignKey to the same parent table, but with a unique identifier

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, uniqueidentifier

I have the following data structure:

- `State` has `state_id` and `name`. (Example: `California`)
- `Area` has `state_id`, `area_id` and `name` (Example: `Area of San Francisco`, which contains some villages and San Francisco)
- `Town` has `town_id`, `area_id`, `state_id`, and `name`. (Example: `Town of San Francisco`)
- `Street` has `street_id`, `town_id`, `area_id`, `state_id` and `name`.

Note the following:

- `state_id` is not a real ID (like an auto increment int), but a fixed number for each state.
- `area_id` is neither an auto increment int, but a fixed number. This means that two different states (big enough to have several areas), will have states with the same ID. (The state of San Francisco will have San Francisco (`area_id = 1`) and the state NY will have NY (`area_id = 1`).
- `town_id`... you guessed it, same as `state_id` and `area_id`.

Don't insist on why the data is structured that way, it goes beyond the scope of this question and beyond what I'm allowed to refactor. So don't waste time on suggesting me to change that. I already know it's wrong, but I'm not allowed to fix it. Full stop.

This means that a town must contain both the `area_id` and the `state_id` for it to be identificable. And a street needs to contain the `town_id`, `area_id` and `state_id` to be identificable.

How can I express that relation with a Django model, so I can do `area.towns` and get all the towns of that area, or `state.streets` and get all the streets in that state?

If the question isn't clear enough I'll be happy to update it with whatever information you need, just ask.

Comment: Have you looked into the ManyToManyField? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: This question is a bit complex to understand. if i got it right, ,maybe unique_togather could help you:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/options/#unique-together

Answer (score 1):

I'd love to address other aspects of the data model, but think that I understand the constraints as you describe them.  I may deviate a little bit with respect to defining the state_id or duplicitive id's.  I don't get them but assume that you can achieve those definitions through a custom save function.

```
class State(models.Model):
    #implicit autoincrement id
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    state_id = models.IntegerField()

    def listAreasByState(self):
        return Area.objects.filter(state=self)

    def listAreasByStateID(self):
        return Area.objects.filter(state_id=self.state_id)


class Area(models.Model):
    #implicit autoincrement id
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    state = models.ForeignKey(State, blank=True, null=Tru)
    state_id = models.IntegerField()
    area_id = models.IntegerField()

....
```

Am I getting the gist of your question.  I'm not clear on where or how you define the state_id, area_id vice Area's auto incremented id.  But it sounds like what you'd like to do is write a custom function to return all childs for every parent.

Comment: Oh, I see. So your suggestion is to use a function instead of a member. That should work, yes. I was too focused on trying to do it with a member. Ok, let me check so would that work. Btw, state ids, area ids and town ids a manually picked/hardcoded. I really don't know why, but I suspect it has something to do with compatibility of other applications.